# Correct way to ask about age

Tags: questions

Recently, my distant relative had a birthday. Is it proper to ask him:

> How old did you get?

In the question, I would like to emphasize the fact that his age has changed recently.

Comment: "How old did you get" would sound odd to a native speaker because you get (become) older, don't become age or acquire it as a thing.  If you are mentioning the birthday, you could add, "How old did you turn?" or even better, as Stew C suggests, "How old are you now?".  You mention "his age".  Men tend to be fine answering questions about their age.  But ask a woman about her age or weight at your own peril.

Comment: "Hey Happy Birthday! I don't remember, is this a milestone birthday?"  They will answer you with thanks and offer the years if they so choose.

Comment: You can get old in English but you don't ask someone how old they got. To get old means: to become old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends. In this situation I would say, "How old did you turn?"
But if you are generally asking how old someone is ask, "how old are you?"

Answer (score 7):

Mm.. not really.  That makes it unclear as to when the event took place that you are referring to.  Instead we would say (AmE): "*How old are you now?*"  Using *now* also makes it clear there was a recent change.

Comment: I agree: **"How old are you now?"** is the usual way of asking for age anywhere in the world in English.